# Javascript assign the same button to start/stop animation

Tags: javascript

So I have this animation, at current state it starts when button is clicked, but it doesn't stop, my intention is to use javascript to assign one button which would start the animation and remove animation property when clicked again (Not pause the animation!) also button should change it's name to "stop" when the animation is running. Would love to get an answer with explanation, since just started with javascript. Thanks in advance! :)

Css:

```
    #kirby {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    /*animation-name: move;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    }
    @keyframes move {
    0% {
    left: 0%;
    }
    49.99999% {
    left: 65%;
    }
    50%{ 
    left: -65%;
    }
    100%{
    left: 0%;
    }
    };
```

Javascript:

```
    var kirby = document.querySelector("#kirby");
    var button1 = document.querySelector("#button1");
    button1.addEventListener ("click", function (){
    kirby.style.animation = "move 5s linear infinite";
    });
```

Comment: By _stopping the animation_ do you mean removing `animation` CSS property when clicked?

Comment: You can clear the animation property... [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gbdebbak/)

Comment: @ThumChoonTat Yes I man to remove animation css property when the button is clicked second time. Having a problem of formulating else statement which tells to remove that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the animation state in a variable, then check for the state every time the `button` is clicked and do stuffs accordingly, like this

```js
var kirby = document.querySelector("#kirby");
var button1 = document.querySelector("#button1");
var playing = false;

button1.addEventListener ("click", function (){
    if ( !playing ) { // If not playing
        kirby.style.animation = "move 5s linear infinite";

        // `this` refers to `button1`
        // `innerText` refers to text content in `button1`
        this.innerText = 'Stop'; // `this refers to `button1`
        playing = true;
    } else {
        kirby.style.animation = ""; // clear the animation property

        // `this` refers to `button1`
        // `innerText` refers to text content in `button1`
        this.innerText = 'Play';
        playing = false;
    }
});
```

```css
#kirby {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    /*animation-name: move;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
}
@keyframes move {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    49.99999% {
        left: 65%;
    }
    50%{ 
        left: -65%;
    }
    100%{
        left: 0%;
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="kirby">kirby</div>
<button id="button1">Start</button>
```

Comment: Well this gives me one of the things I wanted - changes the button text content to "stop" when animation starts, but animation doesn't stop when button is clicked again

Comment: @Agnut. Oops, forgot to change the state. Updated the answer

Comment: Now it works, just one small problem, when I want to start animation second time, the button is not doing anything anymore is there anything that can be done to fix it? :D

Comment: The same button?

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that you added playing=false  in else statement too, it works just fine!! Thank you very much, gave me a pretty good understanding how to continue with this assignment :)

Answer (score 0):

one approach would be assigning a variable to true when clicked and false when unclicked use this variable in if/else condition to start and stop animation

Answer (score -1):

You can assign a custom attribute to the button, say `data-status`, like this:

```
<button data-status="on">Start</button>
```

Now, in your event callback you'll check for that attribute and toggle its value. Something like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button1');

button.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    var status = ev.target.getAttribute('data-status');

    if (status === 'on') {
        //Stop
    }
    else if (status === 'off') {
        //Start
    }
});
```

Comment: What does that "ev" mean and why is it needed?

Comment: The variable 'ev' holds the information related to the event, in this case, the button click event. It is needed in case you don't have access to the 'button' variable.